# Esp8266-01 AT Commands returns partially

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, tcpip

Im trying to get html response from server via esp01 module

when using the serial monitor in arduino studio everything works fine

here is the serial monitor output

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","aaaa.aaaa",80

CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=43


OK
> 
Recv 43 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,227:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sat, 19 Jan 2019 18:42:58 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.2.11
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

10
Hello from server

0

CLOSED
```

but when im trying to do the same from the sketch my response is returned partially

```
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","aaaa.aaaa",80

CONNECT

OK
AT+CIPSEND=43


OK
> 
Recv 43 bytes

SEND OK

+IPD,227:HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: S
```

it ends on the first letter of date for some reason

here is my sketch

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); // RX, TX //serial for comunication with esp
void setup() {
  // Open serial communications and wait for port to open:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  // set the data rate for the SoftwareSerial port
  mySerial.begin(9600);
  mySerial.setTimeout(5000);//dont know if i need this

  delay(10000);

  //check wifi module
  mySerial.println("AT");
  delay(1000);
  if(mySerial.find("OK"))
  {
    Serial.println("Initializing");
  }else{
    Serial.println("Error initializing");
  }
}

void loop() { // run over and over

  Serial.println("go");
mySerial.println("AT+CIPSTART=\"TCP\",\"aaaa.aaaa\",80");
delay(1000);
    while(mySerial.available()){
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
     delay(1);
  }
mySerial.println("AT+CIPSEND=43");
delay(1000);
    while(mySerial.available()){
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
     delay(1);
  }
mySerial.println("GET /load.php HTTP/1.1");
delay(100);
    while(mySerial.available()){
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
     delay(1);
  }
mySerial.println("Host: aaaa.aaaa");
delay(100);
    while(mySerial.available()){
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
     delay(1);
  }
mySerial.println("");
delay(2000);


    while(mySerial.available()){
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
     //delay(100);
  }

delay(5000);

}
```

what is the reason for this behavior? 
how can i fix this?

Comment: your `while (mySerial.available())` ends at the first gap between bytes. the Serial at 9600 baud is very slow

Comment: https://majenko.co.uk/blog/reading-serial-arduino

Comment: looks like your sketch is not waiting for the data stream to finish

Comment: @Juraj increasing baud did not help

Comment: @jsotola how can i add that?

Answer (score 0):

found the solution 
i had t wait for serial input without delay function

```
String sendCommand(String command, const int timeout)
{
  String res = "";
  mySerial.println(command); // send the read character to the wifi
  long int time = millis();
  while( (time+timeout) > millis())
  {
    while(mySerial.available())
    {
      // The esp has data so display its output to the serial window
      char c = mySerial.read(); // read the next character.
      res+=c;
    }
  }
  //Serial.print(response);
  return res;
}
```

Comment: It's OK to accept your own answer if it solves the problem. I think you get 15 rep for that.